# Append to File With try-with-resources

Tags: java, try-catch, java-7, try-with-resources

I'm trying to shift from `try-catch-finally` to `try-with-resources` but having difficulties applying it for appending line to file (adding a line at the bottom).

So far, I've:

```
String toAppend = "this is a new line\n";          
try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("/home/test.txt",true)) {  
    fw.write(toAppend);
} catch(IOException ioe) {
        throw new RehydrateCLIException("Failed to update file", ioe);
}
```

Above, `fw.write(toAppend)` is not recognized because fw is not recognized in scope (and consequentially `write` method).

What am I missing?

The `try` line shows `fw` as an unused variable.

[image]

Comment: I don't see a problem with your code snippet? Compiles for me, except for the unknown exception.

Comment: Not recognized by what?

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: @nullpointer how was the question resolved?

Comment: Are you certain you've posted the actual code, unaltered?  It works fine for me.  Clearly, your screen shot is demonstrating it is not working for you.  Perhaps you need to restart your IDE?

Comment: @AJNeufeld yes, I double and triple checked it.

Comment: @Simply_me you're *sure* you don't have a `;` after the `try (FileWriter fw = ...);`? There must be something like that, otherwise it would be working, as others have noted.

Comment: @AndyTurner I copied the code above as is to my IDE and is shows the same error.

Comment: Is your project set to use Java 1.7 or higher?  Java 1.6 does not do try-with-resources.

Comment: What IDE? What Java version? Etc. Working just fine for me (and everyone else).

Comment: @AJNeufeld checking.... the main reason I tried it is to shift to JDK7.

Comment: The Eclipse IDE allows your project to have JDK7 (or JDK8, JDK9) on the build path, and still have the Java compliance set to 1.6, which will complain on `try (AutoClosable resource = ...) { .. }` statements.  Just having the correct JDK on the build path may not be enough.  It would help to know what IDE you are using (and version), and whether Maven is used to configure the project, etc., in order for us to point you to the exact setting pages to check the proper settings.

Comment: @AJNeufeld thank you, that fixed the issue. I wanted to try JDK7 feature but didnt set the project for it. Thank you!